# Identify and exterminate bug

Tags: pest-control, insect

Please help me identify and exterminate this insect:

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

[image: unknown insect]

Comment: I feel like you might get better results with this over on [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions).  They have a species-identification tag with several "what is this bug" questions.  They might not tell you how to kill it, but could identify it.

Comment: why do you need to exterminate that insect? ..... allow a couple wolf spiders to live in your house and you won't have any insects crawling around

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a silverfish which are a common pest.

[image]

### References

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish
- https://www.pestworld.org/pest-guide/occasional-invaders/silverfish/

Comment: Was going to answer with silverfish. I think they are relatively harmless. But I will click your links. Edit - Apparently they are quite destructive and eat book bindings

Answer (score 4):

That is a [silverfish](https://www.doyourownpestcontrol.com/silverfish.htm).

Eliminating the environment they like may be enough to eradicate them. They like moisture, and cellulose or sugar. Stacks of boxes in a garage, books or magazines in a bathroom or kitchen, and moisture in walls with cellulose insulation or wallpaper are common places where silverfish like to live.

Comment: if they like celulose and house is carpeted  how can we get rid of them ?

Comment: Most carpeting isn't cellulose. Boxes, books and magazines in damp or high humidity areas are the most common place to find them in homes. A good thorough decluttering, vacuuming and moisture control of bathrooms, closets, kitchens and storage areas is the best way to get rid of them.