# What is this pest?

Tags: pest-control

I am seeing this pest in my room and the bathroom:

[image]

The interesting point is that there are TWO types of these. The black ones (as shown above), and the white ones with an exactly similar shape, but entirely white.

I see them crawling on my bathroom's floor and on the walls.

What is this pest? What's the potential harm? and what should be done to get rid of them?

Comment: if my answer was helpful, please click the 'Accept' mark on it :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify and exterminate bug](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/159258/identify-and-exterminate-bug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a Silverfish:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish

[image]

They can eat (and thus destroy) various things, but they're not (generally) as problematic as, say, clothes moth or wood worm.

I lived in a house that was lightly infested with them (probably saw a half-dozen most days) and never observed any specific problems.

Personally, I just ignored them, and if they're only in the bathroom I would definitely not be concerned.

Comment: Naturally, if you search online you'll find plenty of pest control services which will tell you that they're an absolute disaster and you must fix them immediately! You may or may not consider these claims reliable. ;)